ExtJs 6.2.0 upgrade date time picker is stopped working
ExtJs 6.2.0 upgrade date time picker is stopped working Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'unselectable')
ExtJs 6.2.0 upgrade date time picker is stopped working.
this issue started after extjs upgrade so can anyone please help me on this
